# Identify how many times a string exists on a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to search the occurrence of a particular string inside all available stored procedures in `SQL Server`. I know that we can get this by using the below query.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) PrcName
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE DEFINITION LIKE '%SearchStr%'
```

But is there a way we can find out how many times the particular string is available in each stored procedure? This is for estimating the effort modifying the stored procedures.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can create a stored procedure...here is my idea; with your query you can store the procedures names into a temp table, right...then you can do another query where you can extract the text of the stored procedure and you can check line by line, or you can create a table function that returns a table with every line of code into a single column and perform a count...is not that complicated.

Comment: I'm confused about the correlation between occurrences and level of effort for refactoring code. A proc could have one reference to a column, but that value could be used for the rest of the proc and have a huge impact. Or another could have 10 references to a column, but it touches a very narrow section of the code base and has a negligible impact.

Comment: @Hackerman The effort is to replace the string with a new one. We can do that by using notepad ++ also. But need to quality the changes and impact. Also if we use notepad ++, there may be a chance that the format also may change..

Comment: Do you really want to match a string or a token, e.g. searching for "Len" should match "Len( ProductName )", but should it match "PackageLength"?

Answer (score 2):

This will work as tested:

```
;WITH cte as
(
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) PrcName, OBJECT_ID
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE DEFINITION LIKE '%tblNDT%')

select t1.PrcName, (LEN(Definition) - LEN(replace(Definition,'tblNDT',''))) / LEN('tblNDT') Cnt
from cte t1
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules t2 on t1.object_id = t2.object_id
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way of checking how many times something occurs is to take the initial length, replace your string with blanks, recheck the length, and divide by the length of your string:

```
DECLARE @sentence VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @word VARCHAR(100)
SET @word = 'Cool'
SET @sentence = 'This cool sentence is really cool. Cool!'

DECLARE @wordlen INT = (SELECT LEN(@word))


--Original sentence and length
SELECT @sentence AS setencelen
SELECT LEN(@sentence) AS origsentence

--With word removed
SELECT REPLACE(@sentence, 'cool', '') AS shortenedsentence
SELECT LEN(REPLACE(@sentence, 'cool', '')) AS shortenedlen

SELECT LEN(@sentence) - LEN(REPLACE(@sentence, 'cool', '')) AS diffinlength

SELECT (LEN(@sentence) - LEN(REPLACE(@sentence, 'cool', ''))) / @wordlen AS occurrences
```

I have seen this work in some cases and not in others. If you have a bunch of comments that contain the same string, it will count incorrectly.

Comment: @GopakumarN.Kurup Yeah, most systems have that many. So take the logic and put it into a function or a proc and use it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this.

```
DECLARE @cnt AS INT= 1
DECLARE @SearchStr  VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SearchText'
;WITH CTE_SearchStr1
AS
(
SELECT @cnt Cnt, @SearchStr SearchStr UNION ALL
SELECT Cnt + 1, @SearchStr+'%'+SearchStr FROM CTE_SearchStr1
),
CTE_SearchStr2
AS
(
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM CTE_SearchStr1
)
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) ObjectName, MAX(cnt) cnt FROM sys.sql_modules a INNER JOIN CTE_SearchStr2 b ON
a.definition LIKE '%'+b.SearchStr+'%'
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Only problem with the above query is that I can not search for more that 100 times. It will throw the below exception

> Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The statement terminated. The
>   maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

**In my scenario, the number of occurrences are less than 100, but is there a way to overcome this error?**

Comment: Use the [`MaxRecursion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017) query hint. A value of zero will remove the limit.